# measurability of a function -equivalent conditions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$f:(X,\mathcal{M}\to (\overline{\mathbb{R}},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{\overline{R}}))$ then TFAE

a)$f$ is measurable

b)$f^{-1}([a,\infty])$ is measurable $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

c)$f^{-1}([-\infty, a))$is measurable $\forall a\in\mathbb{R}$

Just need some hints.

By def $f$ is measurable if $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{M}$ (i.e measurable ), $\forall A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$

why is $a\Rightarrow b$ proven in the following way

$f^{-1}([a,\infty])=\displaystyle\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(a-\frac{1}{n},\infty])$

and for example $b\Rightarrow c$

$f^{-1}([-\infty, a))=X\setminus f^{-1}([a,\infty])$

I think we are supposed to use the following theorem here:
Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the class of subsets of $Y$ assume $\mathcal{N}=\sigma({\mathcal{E}})$. Then $f:X\to Y$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(A)\in\mathcal{M}$ for all $A\in\mathcal{E}$

so if $f$ is measurable now then by the above theorem $f^{-1}([a,\infty])$ is measurable as $[a,\infty]$ generates $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ so what is the point of writing the inverse image as the intersection of the inverse images ?

Answer (score 1):

$(a) \implies (b). \ $ $(a - 1/n, \infty]$ is $B(\mathbb{\overline{R}})$ for all $n$.  Since a sigma algebra is closed under countable intersection and $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} (a - 1/2, \infty] = [a,\infty]$ you have that the inverse images of these sets are equal.  Prove that equality holds.  Then if that's so, since $\mathcal{M}$ is also closed under countable intersection you have that the interval under question is indeed measurable.

Comment: I have just figured that out now. :) Thank you

Comment: Sie sind willkommen

Comment: Do you need help with the rest then?

Comment: I think I will manage from here. Vielen Dank! :)

Comment: I'm feelin dank too.